# Expanding algebraic powers in python (sympy)

Tags: python, sympy

I'm just wondering if there is an existing method of expanding algebraic powers such as `x**2` out to their multiplicative forms (i.e. `x**2 -> x*x`) in python's Sympy module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no direct support for this. SymPy automatically combines common terms in a multiplication to exponentiation.  The only way to make this not happen is to use the `evaluate=False` mechanism.  For example

```
>>> Mul(x, x, evaluate=False)
x*x
```

There was a discussion on the SymPy mailing list a while back about this exact question (https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sympy/qaJGesRbX_0/discussion).  I posted some code there that will do this.  I'll repeat it here:

```
def pow_to_mul(expr):
    """
    Convert integer powers in an expression to Muls, like a**2 => a*a.
    """
    pows = list(expr.atoms(Pow))
    if any(not e.is_Integer for b, e in (i.as_base_exp() for i in pows)):

        raise ValueError("A power contains a non-integer exponent")
    repl = zip(pows, (Mul(*[b]*e,evaluate=False) for b,e in (i.as_base_exp() for i in pows)))
    return expr.subs(repl)
```

Here's how it works

```
>>> a = Symbol('a')
>>> exp = a**2
>>> print(exp)
a**2
>>> print(pow_to_mul(exp))
a*a
```

I'll put the same caveat here as on the mailing list: "evaluate=False is somewhat of a hack, so be aware that it is fragile.  Some functions will reevaluate the expression, converting it back to Pow.  Other functions will break because some expected invariant will be broken by the evaluate=False expression (e.g., I doubt factor() would work correctly)."

Comment: This is neat and works some of the time. However, as you say the _evaluate_ kwarg is fragile often overlooked, even frequently in the final _expr.subs(repl)_ line. After converting I only want to print to a C string (i.e. I won't perform any more operations on the expression), so is there a way to force the _subs_ method to not evaluate the converted expressions?

Comment: Okay, so it looks like I have solved this by hacking a copy of _xreplace_ to use evaluate=False internally whenever it regenerates a sub-expression. Can you see any problems with this approach?

Comment: It should be possible to write a version of xreplace that does this without hacking anything, i.e., just as a function that takes an expression and a replacement as input and returns the output replaced with `evaluate=False`.

Comment: this does not work in the following case: `exp = a**2*(-1)` it still prints the exponent

Comment: Likewise, this will not fully expand something like `(1 + x**2)**2`. Running it through twice would work for a double exponent like my example, but it's not a silver bullet.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use the `bottom_up` function to apply the transformation to all subexpressions instead of trying to collect all subexpressions into a single subs.

Comment: It would be an excellent addition.  You could paste results into languages like Python and they would work.  But obvious in C, the ** operator doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no such thing, it does the reverse only.

sympy always shows the output in the most simple way, so it will always say:

```
(x**2).expand() -> x**2

simplify(x**2) -> x**2
```

Comment: Is it possible to switch the feature off selectively?

Comment: I haven't seen any options to actually display `x*x`. But, who knows, it is a pretty vast library...

Answer (score 1):

The replace method is well suited in this task for simple expressions:

```
>>> expr = (x**2 + 1)/(x**3 - 2*x)
>>> expr.replace(
... lambda x: x.is_Pow and x.exp > 0,
... lambda x: Mul(*[x.base]*x.exp, evaluate=False))
(x*x + 1)/(-2*x + x*x*x)
```

Tweaking will be necessary to handle things like `1/x**3` or `x**2*(1 + x**2)`. But if you expand the numerator and denominator of the expressions and handle them separately, this may do what you need. And if the bases are always Symbols then this symbol-hackery may do the trick even better:

```
>>> def sack(expr):
...     return expr.replace(
...     lambda x: x.is_Pow and x.exp > 0,
...     lambda x: Symbol('*'.join([x.base.name]*x.exp)))
...
>>> sack(-x**2)
-x*x
>>> sack(x**2*(1 + x**3)
x*x*(x*x*x + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up from Aaron's accepted answer and my comment on it, this is the version of `xreplace` I am using instead of the final `subs` line to avoid sub-expressions being evaluated (and thus losing the expansion of the power to a chain of multiplications).

```
def non_eval_xreplace(expr, rule):
    """
    Duplicate of sympy's xreplace but with non-evaluate statement included
    """
    if expr in rule:
        return rule[expr]
    elif rule:
        args = []
        altered = False
        for a in expr.args:
            try:
                new_a = non_eval_xreplace(a, rule)
            except AttributeError:
                new_a = a
            if new_a != a:
                altered = True
            args.append(new_a)
        args = tuple(args)
        if altered:
            return expr.func(*args, evaluate=False)
    return expr
```

I was thinking this functionality could be added to the existing `xreplace` in the SymPy library by letting it take `**kwargs` that are passed to the `expr.func` call. Is this something you are interested in doing, or would this be unnecessarily complex for the majority of users? (or did I misunderstand your comment above and is there a simpler way to do this?)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers do not handle `-x**2` so I used regex instead to solve only for powers of 2. I understand this is a little hacky but it worked for me.

```
from sympy.printing import ccode
import re
CPOW = re.compile(r'pow\((?P<var>[A-Za-z_]\w*)\s*,\s*2\s*\)')

def to_c_code(expr):
    code = ccode(expr)
    # sympy has a hard time unsimplifying x**2 to x*x
    # replace all pow(var,2) with var*var
    code = re.sub(CPOW, r'\g<var>*\g<var>', code)
    return code
```